# Adding a view to a SpriteKit scene in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, iad

I'm trying to add an iAd banner to a SpriteKit scene, but I found out that I can't do that without adding a view/subview to the SpriteKit scene. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the `view` of your SKScene:

```
self.view?.addSubview(yourSubview)
```

Comment: And how should I create that subview?

Comment: Well you can add a UIButton or whatever you want. A subview doesn't need to be an UIView. Just initialize it like you do with other objects. var yourview = UIView(....)

Answer (score 1):

`SKScene` provides `didMoveToView`, which in turn provides the current `SKView` on which you can use `addSubview`, since it inherits from `UIView`.

Another option is to directly access the view of the scene and call `addSubview`:

```
self.view?.addSubview(subview)
```